# Cant edit pages ! There has been a critical error on your website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions

Tags: wordpress

when I tried to create or edit page, it said "There has been a critical error on your website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions." !
what can I do?

Comment: "*What can I do?*" How about "*check your site admin email inbox for instructions*"?

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the plugin directory and check if you still see this error. If you are able to see the website, there should be some issue with some plugin.